# Find current nav item and assign class to li

Tags: jquery, css, nav

I'm using the code below to assign an `active` class to the current nav item.

```
$(function () {
  var page = window.location.pathname,
  find = new RegExp(page == '/' ? window.location.origin + '/?$' : page.replace(/\/$/, ''));
  $('nav a').each(function () {
    if (find.test(this.href.replace(/\/$/, ''))) {
      $(this).addClass('active');
    }
  });
});
```

How could I use [`parent`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) to assign the class to the li tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I have understood your question right, you want to add class to parent of a tag. This is how you'll do it.

```
$(this).parent().addClass('active');
```

Comment: Wowwwww I'm a moron. Thank you! I'll accept your answer after the 10 minute requirement.

Comment: `this` needs to be surrounded by parenthesis. Stack won't let me edit the answer because it's under 6 characters.